# What do 'they' and 'their' refer to in this paragraph?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns, antecedents

What does 'they' refer to in the following paragraph?

> You see, what we’re doing is we’re bringing up children and educating
> them to live the same sort of lives we’re living, in order that **they**
> may justify **themselves** and find satisfaction in life by bringing up
> **their children** to bring up **their children** to do the same thing. So
> it’s all retch and no vomit—it never gets there. And so, therefore,
> it’s so important to consider this question: “What do I desire?”

I guess the first **they** and **themselves** refer to 'we'. Also, the sentence uses '**their children**' twice; I think the first one means 'our children' and second one refers to 'our grandchildren'. Am I understanding the sentence correctly?

Comment: I think you meant "What DO 'they' and 'their ' refer to?", right?

Comment: The whole paragraph is a bit of a mess; I certainly wouldn't use it as an example of how to write English.

Comment: _So it’s all retch and no vomit_ I have not heard this expression before.  Is it common?

Comment: @JohnGordon I don't think I'd heard it before either. Some info on it at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91874/meaning-of-all-retch-and-no-vomit

Comment: Apparently this quote is transcribed from Alan Watts' seminar "Do You Do It, or Does It Do You?" (specifically, a portion frequently referenced as "What if money was no object?"). [Here's a timestamped clip that includes these lines of audio from it.](https://youtu.be/khOaAHK7efc?t=136)

Comment: Strange, not even the answers (as far as I see) have noticed the first *them* in "we're bringing up children and educating **them** to live ...". This *them* quite clearly refers to *children*, and so it's natural to conclude that all following *they, them, their* etc. do as well. As they do.

Answer (score 16):

They and themselves would seem to refer to "children".  There is no other third person plural noun it could refer to.  It can't mean "we".  Don't use "they" to mean "we".

So "their children" means "our children's children" (ie our grandchildren) and the second "their children" means "their children's children" (ie our great-grand-children)

This looks like transcribed speech, rather than written English. It could benefit from some editing for clarity.

Comment: I think they used the parallel phrases for rhetorical effect, at the slight expense of clarity. It suggests that this should repeated in every generation, not just these three specific ones.

Comment: Yep. Apparently this quote is transcribed from Alan Watts' seminar "Do You Do It, or Does It Do You?" (specifically, a portion frequently referenced as "What if money was no object?"). [Here's a timestamped clip that includes these lines of audio from it.](https://youtu.be/khOaAHK7efc?t=136) Watts is commenting on society at large here (or at least "Western society") – he's saying that basically everyone is raising their children in this way, and thus the next generation repeats the cycle, and so on.

Answer (score 7):

> that **they**

A new group comprised of our own children.

> may justify **themselves**

The same group (our children) but now referring to that groups self.

> and find satisfaction in life by bringing up **their children**

The previous groups children, our grand children.

> to bring up **their children**

the group comprised of our grandchildren from above, but now referring to their own children (our great grandchildren)

> to do the same

Additional clarity could be achieved by referring to the named groups:

> that **our children** may justify themselves and find satisfaction in life by bringing up **our grandchildren** to bring up **our great-grandchildren** to do the same

It should be pointed out that the set of pronouns (they/them/their) can also be the preferred singular pronoun for an individual as well.

Comment: and for completeness, "they/them/their" can be used to refer to an arbitrary singular person of yet-to-be-determined gender, for example in a job advertisement.

Answer (score 6):

While others have correctly identified what the they/their refer to in a strict sense, a literal reading of the referents misses some subtleties in the rhetorical structure.

The repetition of "their children" (and the associated switch in who "their" refers to) is likely deliberate. Setting up the repeated structure "*bringing up their children to bring up their children*" invites the reader/listener to mentally continue the pattern. ("... their children to bring up their children to bring up ...")

The argument isn't limited to the grandchildren and great-grandchildren, the intent is that the pattern and argument would apply and continue to all descendants. The repetition of "their children" as-is brings that concept into the sentence in a way that explicit references (e.g. "bringing up our grandchildren to bring up our great-grandchildren") doesn't. It also differs from simply saying "all our descendants" by explicitly invoking the concept of an unbroken chain of parents passing things on directly to their children, versus passing something from the ancestor directly to a distant generation.

Reading things this way makes the otherwise unclear change of who "their" is referring to less unclear. The precise people to which "their" refers to in "*bringing up their children to bring up their children*" doesn't quite matter, as the construct is read as a whole, implying a whole collection of descendants, rather than any particular generation.